# How to implement session with express-session?

Tags: mysql, node.js, session-cookies, express-session, session-store

I’m considering using session in my node.js application.

I understand the following:
- session-cookie use cookie to save session data on the client side
- express-session use cookie to store a sessionID and all the session data are stored on the server side

I’m worried about security so I would choose express-session.
But the Documentation say that by default express-session store data in memory and this not envisageable in production.

So my questions are:
How do you implement session in your application?
Do session stores are not influencing performance?
If not, which session store would you recommend me? (my application is using MySql as database)

Thank you very much for your help.
Regards.

Comment: Presumably you haven't read the `express-session` docs fully? As if you had, you would've came across the [compatible stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) section and discovered [express-mysql-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session)

Comment: I did find the express-mysql-session module but I also found that using database to store session could be problematic... I’m not using any cluster app so file storing method could maybe work?

Comment: well this is the type of information you should state in your question. So if you don't want to store state in your DB then where do you want to store it? I'm intrigued...

Comment: Yes you’re right, sorry for the first question. I was a little bit confused. I thought that using the mysql database where all the data related to the app are stored would affect the performance of the app. But since you proposed this solution I now assume that it wouldn’t affect the performance. (I was referring to Redis or MongoDB in my previous comment but having only ONE database should be easier to manage) I’ll start digging at express-mysql-session!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to manage session data is tokens.

You can easily use 'passport' for expressjs and nodejs.

You can generate a token that is signed in your NodeJS backend with a private key and identifiable by the public key. These tokens can even be revoked.

They are passed into the 'authorization' header as a web standard.

Here is an example of validation I use for extracting and checking a generated token a user has provided.

```
module.exports.ensureAuthorized = function ensureAuthorized(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let bearerToken;
        let bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
        if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
            let bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
            bearerToken = bearer[1];
            req.token = bearerToken;
            this.userPayload(req.token).then((result) => {
                if (!result) {
                    return res.status(403).json({message:"Failed to verify token supplied in authorization header", data: null});
                }else{
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(403).json({message:"Failed to supply token in authorization header.", data: null});
        }
    });
};
```

And here is my REST API call for a user attempting to login: (that generates a valid token)

```
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let config = require('../../misc/config');
global.atob = require("atob");
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.getLogin = function(req, res) {
    const btoaAuth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
    const [username, password, rememberMe] = atob(btoaAuth).toString().split(':');
    if(username && password) {
        usersModel.findOneAndUpdate({username: username},{lastLogin: new Date(),})
            .exec(function (err, userResult) {
                if(err) return res.status(500).json({message: "Server failed search users", data: err});
                if(!userResult) return res.status(500).json({message: "Username invalid", data: err});
                userResult.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) {  return res.status(500).json({message: "Server failed to process user login", data: err});}

                    // Password did not match
                    if (!isMatch) {  return res.status(403).json({message: "Password incorrect", data: err}); }
                    // Success
                    let token = jwt.sign({_id: userResult._id,username: userResult.username, exp: rememberMe === 'true'? Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100) : Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60) }, config.jwtSecret);
                    let obj = {};
                    obj['profile'] = userResult;
                    obj['profile']['password'] = undefined;
                    obj['token'] = token;
                    return res.status(200).json({message: "Successful login", data: obj});
                });
            });
    }else{
        return res.status(400).json({message: "Username and password are required", data: req.body});
    }
};
```

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start with this code - unresolvable Promise, returning incorrect status codes and leaking internal information to the client :( I hope you aren't running this in a deployed production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer not to use token.